# Python reading unicode from local files

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to read some unicode files that I have locally. How do I read unicode files while using a list? I've read the python docs,  and a ton of stackoverflow Q&A's, which have answered a lot of other questions I had, but I can't find the answer to this one.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Sorry, my files are in utf-8.

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: There is no such thing as "a Unicode file". There are several *encodings* that can be used to encode Unicode strings into bytes, the most common of which is `utf-8`. Is that the encoding of your files? If not, which one is? Do your files have a [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: Yes, my files are in UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open UTF-8-encoded files by using

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("myutf8file.txt", encoding="utf-8-sig") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        # do something with line
```

Be aware that `codecs.open()` does not translate `\r\n` to `\n`, so if you're working with Windows files, you need to take that into account.

The `utf-8-sig` codec will read UTF-8 files with or without a [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (and strip it if it's there). On writing, you should use `utf-8` as a codec because [the Unicode standard recommends against writing a BOM in UTF-8 files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/20670).

Comment: It's fairly easy to ignore any UTF-8 BOM that might be at beginning of the input file with an `if infile.read(len(codecs.BOM_UTF8)) != codecs.BOM_UTF8: infile.seek(0)` following the `with` statement.

Comment: @martineau: It's probably easier to use the `utf-8-sig` codec for this (but you shouldn't use it for writing, therefore I hadn't included it in my answer).

Comment: Then it's even easier than I thought. You seem overly concerned about writing files considering it's not even mentioned in the OP's question.

Comment: @martineau: I guess you're right. Well, at one point or another *something*  will be output by a program, and my guess is that this will have something to do with the files the program has read. I have edited my answer a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Tim Pietzcker and @martineau.